# How to reply in thread from slack bot using JBot

Tags: java, spring-boot, bots, slack

Whenever I receive a message, I need to Slack bot to reply in the thread and continue the conversation there.

I am using below dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.ramswaroop.jbot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbot</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please let me know how to implement it using JBot. Any suggestions will be appreciated.